# Чтение массива из файла в таблицу с++

Tags: c++, массивы, файлы

Из файла нужно считать массив в таблицу, а затем производить манипуляции с этой таблицей:

- добавление строк и столбцов в конец;
- вставка строк и столбцов в указанное место;
- удаление выбранной строки или столбца.

Вот пример файла, из которого нужно считать массив:

```
char* myvec5 [5][5] = {
        {"str00","str01","str02","str03","str04"},//sometext 
        {"str00","str01","str02","str03","str04"},
        {"str00","str01","str02","str03","str04"},
        {"str00","str01","str02", "str03","str04"},
        {"str00","str01","str02","str03","str04"}
    };
```

Файл может содержать различный код на с++.
Ну, вот наработки кода:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

#include<algorithm>
#include<iterator>
#include<sstream>

using namespace std;

string **row_add(string **arr, int &R, int C, int pos) {

    R++;
    string **new_arr = new string*[R];

    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        new_arr[i] = new string[C];

    for (int i = 0, ti = 0; i < R; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) 
            if (i == pos)
                new_arr[i][j] = "row";
            else
                new_arr[i][j] = arr[ti][j];
            if (i != pos) 
                ti++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < R - 1; i++)
        delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
    arr = NULL;

    return new_arr;
}

string **col_add(string **arr, int R, int &C, int pos) {

    C++;
    string **new_arr = new string*[R];

    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        new_arr[i] = new string[C];

    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) 
        for (int j = 0, tj = 0; j < C; j++) {
            if (j == pos)
                new_arr[i][j] = "col";
            else new_arr[i][j] = arr[i][tj];
            if (j != pos)
                tj++;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < R; i++)
        delete[] arr[i];
    delete[] arr;
    arr = NULL;

    return new_arr;
}

string **col_delete(string **arr, int R, int &C, int pos) {
    for (int j = pos; j < C - 1; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < R; i++) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[i][j + 1];
        }
    }
    C--;

    return arr;
}

string **row_delete(string **arr, int &R, int C, int pos) {
    for (int i = pos; i < R - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = arr[i + 1][j];
        }
    }
    R--;

    return arr;
}

int main() {

    string file;
    cout << "Enter a name of file: ";
    cin >> file;

    string filename = file + ".txt";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(filename);

    if (!fin) {
        cout << "Error reading file.\n";
        exit(1);
    }

    string line, line2;
    int row, col;
//  fin >> row >> col;
    fin >> line >> line2;
    replace_if(line.begin(), line.end(),
        [](const char& c) { return ((c == '[') || (c == ']')); },
        ' ');
    replace_if(line2.begin(), line2.end(),
        [](const char& c) { return ((c == '[') || (c == ']')); },
        ' ');

    row = atoi(line.c_str());
    col = atoi(line2.c_str());

    string **a = new string *[row];

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        a[i] = new string[col];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            fin >> a[i][j];
//          getline(fin, a[i][j]);

            replace_if(a[i][j].begin(), a[i][j].end(),
                [](const char& c) { return ((c == '{') || (c == ',') || (c == '}')); },
                ' ');

                auto it = std::remove_if(a[i][j].begin(), a[i][j].end(), [&](char c) { return c == '"'; });
                a[i][j] = std::string(a[i][j].begin(), it);

    //      getline(fin, a[i][j], ' ');
        //  fin.ignore();
            cout << a[i][j] << "\t ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    char key;
    bool menu = true;

    while (menu) {

        cout << "***MENU***" << endl;
        cout << "1.Add column\n";
        cout << "2.Add row\n";
        cout << "3.Delete column\n";
        cout << "4.Delete row\n";
        cout << "5.Save results in file\n";
        cout << "0.Exit\n";

        cout << "Choose your action. Type a command: \n";
        cin >> key;

        switch (key) {

        case '1': 

            int colpos;
            cout << "\nEnter the number of column to insert: \n";
            cin >> colpos;
            a = col_add(a, row, col, colpos);

            cout << "\nNew array: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    cout << a[i][j] << "\t ";
                } 
                cout << endl;
            }

            break;

        case '2':

            int rowpos;
            cout << "\nEnter the number of row to insert: \n";
            cin >> rowpos;
            a = row_add(a, row, col, rowpos);

            cout << "\nNew array: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    cout << a[i][j] << "\t ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }

            break;

        case '3':
            int NumberDeleteCol;
            cout << "\nEnter the number of the column to remove: \n";
            cin >> NumberDeleteCol;

            a = col_delete(a, row, col, NumberDeleteCol);

            cout << "\nNew array: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    cout << a[i][j] << "\t ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            break;

        case '4':
            int NumberDeleteRow;
            cout << "\nEnter the number of the row to delete: \n";
            cin >> NumberDeleteRow;

            a = row_delete(a, row, col, NumberDeleteRow);

            cout << "\nNew array: \n";
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    cout << a[i][j] << "\t ";
                }
                cout << endl;
            }
            break;

        case '5':
        {
            ofstream ofout;
            ofout.open(filename);

            ofout << row << " " << col << "\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
                    ofout << a[i][j] << " ";
                }
                ofout << endl;
            }
            ofout.close();

            break;
        }

        case '0':
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            cout << "You entered wrong command! Please, try another: \n";
            break;
        }
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Непонятно: чего надо-то?

Comment: Надо считать из файла содержимое массива. То есть только 
str00 str01 str02 str03 str04
str00 str01 str02 str03 str04
str00 str01 str02 str03 str04
str00 str01 str02 str03 str04
str00 str01 str02 str03 str04

Comment: Ваш файл, из которого надо считывать данные, является текстовым файлом с исходными кодами?

Comment: @Arkady, да, это текстовый файл с исходными кодами.